# cygwin undefined refernce to _gsl_rng_ windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, gsl

I am using windows 7. For C++, I installed eclipse for java first and then added cdt to it. I also installed cygwin to my system. Also, changed the path of environment variables to `C:\Programs\Cygwin\bin`. I have used gsl in the program like

```
service_gen = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_default);
```

I have also included the lib file

```
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
```

But when I give command make from cygwin it is giving me error:
`undefined reference to _gsl_rng_default` and so on. I also checked whether gsl folder exists in my cygwin folder or not, and it is there. I have been trying to solve this problem for hours and nothing works. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `C:\Programs\Cygwin\lib\lapack` to my environment variables. Lapack has gsl and its path was needed!